# How to include full .NET prerequisite for Wix Burn installer

Tags: .net, wix, burn

I'm writing a managed Bootstrapper using Wix Burn and this Bootstrapper depends on .NET 4. If the .NET 4 is not installed on the machine, burn downloads it, installs it and then runs managed bootstrapper.
But, I need to support also fully offline scenarios where .NET 4 can't be downloaded. How can I embed .NET 4 installer into my package so that it can be installed for managed bootstrapper to run?

Wix documentation [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html) says "*Target your bootstrapper application to the version of .NET built into the operating system. For Windows 7, this is .NET 3.5.*" but I can't afford that, I need to bring full .NET installer with me as a prerequisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own `PackageGroup` that contains an `ExePackage` element that points to the full .net installer. This is similar to how you would include other installation packages in your bootstrapper. Note that you will have to download the full .NET installer locally to your build machine. For a thorough code example, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx) by Heath Stewart.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. Another part of answer is that I had to define "WixMbaPrereqPackageId" with value of that custom ExePackage ID so that bootstrapper knows what to install as prerequisite.