# using WIX3.11 to install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 10

Tags: wix, .net-3.5

I am using `WiX` to install my app that needs `SQL Express 2008R2`, but `SQL` uses `.NET Framework 3.5`. `Framework 3.5` in `Windows 10` is installed from 'Add/Remove Windows Components'. When I try to open `dotnetfx35.exe` it can't be opened, but when I run installation from Wix I see this installation [log](http://pastebin.com/p3KNBf0d). Why `.NET Framework 3.5` cannot be installed? How can I install `.NET-3.5` on `Windows 10` and `Windows 7` offline?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include full .NET prerequisite for Wix Burn installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633474/how-to-include-full-net-prerequisite-for-wix-burn-installer)

Comment: [the answer on StackOverflow _](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65086360/1182718)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a WiX Bundle installer to group the SQL Express installer with an offline installer for the correct version of the .NET framework:

```
<Bundle Name="MyInstaller" Version="1.1.1.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="YOUR-GUID-HERE">

  <Chain>
    <ExePackage Id="SQLInstaller" SourceFile="Files\SQLInstaller.exe"/>
    <ExePackage Id="NETInstaller" SourceFile="Files\NETInstaller.exe"/>
  </Chain>

</Bundle>
```

This assumes that the two installers you wish to chain together are both .exe files. If either is an .msi file, use a corresponding `<MsiPackage .../`> element instead.

Comment: The target is how to install .net on Windows 10 offline. Because framework 3.5 in windows 10 make install from 'Add/Remove Windows Components'. I need to know, how can I do it by wix.

Comment: You need to find an offline installer for .NET 3.5 and build that into a WiX bundle as described above.

Comment: it has error log when install from wix https://pastebin.com/p3KNBf0d If I try to open exe file, it's even do not open